# Trigger to cascade updates to a second table

Tags: postgresql, trigger, update

In my PostgreSQL 9.6 database, I am trying to update 2 fields in `table2` with a trigger when `table1` is modified.

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION schema.maj_tbl2()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$

begin
UPDATE schema.table2
SET (contributor, code_tranche) = (user, table1.code_tranche) from schema.table1
where NEW.gid = table2.gid;
return NEW;
END;

$BODY$
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_maj_table2
BEFORE UPDATE
ON schema.table1
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE schema.maj_tbl2();
```

The 2 fields in `table2` are modified the same way but for the entire table with the sames values. I can't update just the row in `table2` concerned by the update in `table1`. I feel something is wrong with the `where` condition but can't fix it.

Comment: Have you tried simply inserting a value into a temporary table in your function and commenting out the `UPDATE...` just to see if you receive the `NEW.gid` value?

Comment: `user` is a reserved work in PostgreSQL, your unquoted use of it in the function does not refer to the column, but rather the name of the currently logged on user.  Either quote it with double quotes, or better yet don't use that as the name of a column at all.

Answer (score 2):

While this trigger function is expensively incorrect and needs to be fixed, it can't explain the problem you describe. There must be some other cause, not evident from your question, yet. Some other broken trigger on `table1` or `table2`?

***This*** trigger updated the same row in `table2` once for every row in `table1` and the final value of `table2.code_tranche` was an arbitrary pick from `table1`.

Remove `from schema.table1`:

```
UPDATE schema.table2
SET   (contributor, code_tranche) = (user, NEW.code_tranche) from schema.table1
WHERE  table2.gid = NEW.gid;
```

And I assume you are aware that [`user` is s synonym for `current_user`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-SESSION-TABLE), returning the user name of current execution context. If it's supposed to be a column name, you have to use `NEW."user"` instead. (But never use reserved words as identifiers to begin with - like jjanes commented.)

Typically, this kind of trigger indicates a problem with your db design. Try to remove redundancy. Storing information in *one* table should suffice.

Comment: Thanks but contributor is still replaced by the user name for all rows...(and I am aware that user is synonym for current_user :))

Comment: @Leehan: The `WHERE` condition clearly says `WHERE  table2.gid = NEW.gid`. So either all your rows in `table2` have the same `gid` or you are updating multiple rows in `table1` (by accident). Or you have additional triggers on `table1` or `table2`? Or the wrong schema name is not just in your question and you are calling a different function than you think you do.

Comment: Obviously, gid in table2 are unique because gid is the primary key. For the multiple rows updated, I have others triggers ont table1, maybe there is a "conflict".

Comment: @Leehan: Some other trigger may be the culprit then. What you displayed for trigger `trg_maj_table2` needed fixing, but it can't explain the problem you describe.

Comment: When I insert a row in `table1`, a first trigger create a row in `table2` as well. If the trigger we are talking about (the second) is disabled then I keep all contributors(=users). IF I enable the second trigger and make the same insert, all contributors are replaced in `table2`. But if I disable the trigger, make the insert and enable the trigger, there it works well : I can update a row in `table1` and contributor in `table2` is updated, just this one.

Comment: @Leehan: I suggest you start a new question about the first trigger then. With all relevant details, incl. table definitions and all triggers on `table1` and `table2`.  Maybe link to this one for context.